# Getting a VF Component to communicate with a new tab?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, browser

I want to implement some copy functionality that opens a new tab with the original object being copied, while the copying takes place on the original tab.

Since the user gets navigated to the new tab with the original object, I want to be able to notify them that their copy was processed successfully. Additionally, I want to prevent them from continuing to copy the object while the current copy process is taking place.

How would I be able to get the original tab to notify the already opened new tab of it's copying status? In the backend I can only think of using some static boolean variable that updates on the status of the copy process, but I'm not sure if this would be the best way to go about this. Does anyone have any suggestions on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: A new browser tab? Lightning tab? Something else?

Comment: @sfdcfox a new browser tab, sorry